# BackHandler.removeEventListener is not working

Tags: react-native

I use `BackHandler.exitApp();` in my first screen, but when i navigate to another screen and click android back button, it still exit application.

I have used `bind` in my constructor, so i can't figure it out why `removeEventListener` is not working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code with `BackHandler` just like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.backPressed = this.backPressed.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPressed);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPressed);
    }
  }

  backPressed() {
    BackHandler.exitApp();
  }
```

Comment: What sort of navigation are you using? Are you sure that your first screen un-mounts and removes the listener? Can you please add a `console.log` before the listener and see if it logs when you change the screen.

Comment: I use `react-navigation` You're right, i try to use `console.log` and when navigate to another screen `componentWillUnmount` is not working. Find others discuss this https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1554.  I still can't find how to fix it.

Comment: If you are pushing a new screen to the stack then it is the expected behavior. Unless you pop the screen it does not unmount.

Comment: I can't unmount it. Because it is my main screen... Is any way can i set some method to know it that navigate to another screen ?

Comment: You can use [`addListener`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) to know if you are in your main page and remove the listener before you navigate to another screen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but there is no way out to know i navigate to another screen.

Comment: How do you navigate to another screen?

Comment: By using `this.props.navigation.navigate` but not only a button in main screen , i still has a drawer menu .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it using this code. Hope this helps you.

```
goBack=()=>{
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
    return true;
}
componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.goBack);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.goBack);
}
```

I add this to the other screen that not want to exit.